# Average waiting time

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

who can help me to resolution of this statistic exercise? below the track: Caio go in a bank,the number of customers ahead him are described by a Poisson random variable of parameter a>0. Calculate the average waiting time knowing that: -the waiting time is given by the sum of service time of single person. -the timing of customer service that precede it are modeled as random variables, independent, marginally exponential of parameter lambda >0.

///// I thought that average waiting time is given by theorem of conditional mean: E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]; then call: Ta average waiting time -> (Ta=Summation of Ts) ,Ts time service customer ,X number of customer.

E[Ta]=E[E[Ta|X]] is right? What will i do now?. Thank all!

Comment: Please put some work in your question. Now it is hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ideas:

The average waiting time is then the sum of the service time for all customers ahead him. It is known that the number of customers ahead have a poisson(a) distribution, that means the service time (for serving a single customer) will have an exponential distribution with expected value of (1/a). Then the average waiting time is = (#of customers)*(the expected service time for one customer).

Comment: Ok,how much are customers X? i.e. X=E[poisson(a)]= a ? is right? so (average waiting time)= a/lambda

Comment: The number of customers are X... the answer is X/a ... I guess!

Comment: X is Poisson random variable,so for my opinion we will consider average of X that is equivalent at his parameter a, (E[X]=a). probably i'm confuse..

Comment: a/lambda is more accurate, regarding a as the number of customers per unit time and lambda is the parameter of the exponential distribution... which have an expected value of 1/lambda.